# How to Get a List of Assemblies in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies

I need to get a list of assemblies in a directory. Is there another way than this?

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.dll")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed assemblies can also be EXEs.  And your code just gets files with the extension "dll". Ntive DLLs, which are not assemblies, would also be returned.

In the few occasions I needed to do this, I simply got a list of all files (similar to what you've done), and then used Assemby.LoadFrom to attempt to load each, trappig the exception in the event its native.  The typical exception is a ReflectionTypeLoadException, though you also may get this if a reference can't be resolved.

Comment: I realize this, that why I asked.